# Convert java byte array to C# base64 string

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Input);
sbyte[] signed = Array.ConvertAll(bytes, b => unchecked((sbyte)b));
byte[] y = (byte[])(object)signed;
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(y, 0, bytes.Length);
string url = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
return base64String;
```

I am sending byte array of an image from android app and saving in database.But when i am trying to convert it in base64 string in c# it is not showing the image.any please help.

Here is the byte array string received from app

```
[B@27943481
```

And c# converted base64 string is

```
 data:image/png;base64,W0JAMjc5NDM0ODE=
```

Please help to convert it in c#.

Answer (score 0):

the string stored into the Input Property is encoded in Ascii? if so, use

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Input); // or Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Input)
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
string url = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
return base64String;
```

that should do the job.